# How to implement fair division(?) with buffer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, division

For the sake of explaining, imagine I have 101 entities. The entities are all people.

In the first entity, it has x amount of "potatoes", I want it to have y potatoes, for now I shall use 950 as an example, intentionally choosing a more awkward number than 1000 for testing.

```
var personOne = {
     ...
     potatoes: 100
}
```

I have 100 more of these entities which may have any number of potatoes, but I set a constant buffer that at least 100 for the sake of example again - have to remain with each person.

This means for all of the entities that have over 100, I will be taking some from them - I want this to be shared proportionally across all of them, so that 850 aren't taken from the first two or three, but 10 or 5 taken from all those that are capable of providing such an amount.

Any ideas for an approach?

Optionally: I am using more properties than one "potatoes" property, but I plan on looping through each type and re-using the method that I find to each. I am unsure as to whether this could affect the answer.

**Important / Simplified**
The one entitiy is pulling "potatoes" from all of the other entities, they are not being distributed evenly across all of them - they are being taken to one entity. I just do not want to do it in a way that is not proportional across all other 100 entities.

This is more taxation than cake-cutting. I am struggling to google for or think of the correct name for the mathematical problem.

Comment: sum up the excess potatoes and divide by the number of participants...?

Comment: Some participants may not necessary have the result of the average.

950 / 100 = 9 or 10 depending on rounding, I am saying they must KEEP 100, they may not have 100.

Does that help? I appreciate the use of ellipsis to make me feel like a moron by the way.

Comment: The ellipsis is more to emphasize that i am not sure i fully understand the question and am making a best guess. I was thinking about the sum of Max(0, potatoes - 100) and take it away for every participant, divide that by 101 and give that back to every participant. What happens with rounding is not clear. If you want some otherwise weighted transfer, more information would be useful.

Comment: Calculate median of differences and use that to help sort out proportinality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this time i understood the problem. I would calculate the percentage of excess potatoes needed to get the desired amount of potatoes and take that percentage of each participant's excess potatoes, or all if there are not enough total.

Here is some demonstration code to clarify. It is probably overly verbose but should only serve to show the intention anyways. I assumed a very precise potato-cutter is available, as there was no rule specified about what to do about rounding. The outputs are the potatoes of the participants before and after the redistribution. I set `NUMBER_OF_PARTICIPANTS` to `4` so the output is somewhat readable.

```js
const MAXIMUM_START_POTATOES = 1234;
const MINIMUM_KEPT_POTATOES = 100;
const ENTITY_TAKING_POTATOES = 0;
const DESIRED_POTATOES = 950;
const NUMBER_OF_PARTICIPANTS = 4;

//generate NUMBER_OF_PARTICIPANTS entities with random amount of potatoes
let entities = [];
for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PARTICIPANTS; i++) {
  entities.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAXIMUM_START_POTATOES + 1)));
}

console.log(entities);

let required_potatoes = DESIRED_POTATOES - entities[ENTITY_TAKING_POTATOES];

if (required_potatoes <= 0) console.log("nothing to do.");
else {
  let excess_potatoes = 0;
  //Sum excess available potatoes
  for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PARTICIPANTS; i++) {
    if (i === ENTITY_TAKING_POTATOES) continue;
    excess_potatoes += Math.max(0, entities[i] - MINIMUM_KEPT_POTATOES);
  }

  if (excess_potatoes < required_potatoes) {
    //just take all excess potatoes
    for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PARTICIPANTS; i++) {
      if (i === ENTITY_TAKING_POTATOES) continue;
      entities[i] = Math.min(entities[i], MINIMUM_KEPT_POTATOES);
    }
    entities[ENTITY_TAKING_POTATOES] += excess_potatoes;
  } else {
    //calculate percentage of the excess potatoes that is needed
    let percentage_required = required_potatoes / excess_potatoes;
    //Take that percentage off every participant's excess potatoes
    for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PARTICIPANTS; i++) {
      if (i === ENTITY_TAKING_POTATOES) continue;
      entities[i] -= Math.max(0, entities[i] - MINIMUM_KEPT_POTATOES) *  percentage_required;
    }
    //Assume double precision is enough for this to never be an issue
    entities[ENTITY_TAKING_POTATOES] = DESIRED_POTATOES;
  }
  console.log(entities);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Case 1. enough potatoes for everyone to have over 100 of them: put all potatoes together and divide evenly.

Case 2. Not enough potatoes for everyone to have 100. Sum the *excess over 100* for those who have + sum all potatoes of those with less than 100, divide the collected potatoes between those with under 100.

(yes, case 2 will imply that some of those under 100 will end with less potatoes than they started. Not fair? Well, maybe you shouldn't protect the 1-percenters that much if there aren't enough potatoes for everybody :) But I digress)

Comment: Please re-read the question, I have edited it. Thank you very much for answering.

It's awesome that you made the 1 percent joke, I think you get it. Hopefully the additional information helps, it's awkward to explain but I'm trying.